Manage dependancy confilts in fastapi or flask app
I'd like some assistance in automating the management of dependency conflicts in my Flask and FastAPI applications. The projects I'm working on require different packages I've developed myself, each with its own set of dependencies. However, integrating these packages often leads to conflicts, such as when a package requires NumPy 2.0, but my project is running NumPy 3.0. Currently, I manually adjust versions in my requirements.txt file, but it's cumbersome and time-consuming, especially across multiple projects. Is there a more automated solution to handle or prevent these conflicts and facilitate easier image creation without dependency issues?
a tool or a tutorial
for example

my_package1: use numpy==1.8
my_packge2: use numpy==2.1
myproject1: in his venv i have in my req.txt
numpy==3.0
my_package1
my_package2
how to avoid dependence conflicts when i do a pip install req.txt without change manually change version of dependances one by one?


if dependencies for different projects are conflicting it's a sign you need to use separate environment for each project (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html for the common solution and https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/ for more detail). If it's different dependencies of the same project then there's no easy answer, you need to find library versions that are compatible with each other

for example
my_package1: use numpy==1.8
my_packge2: use numpy==2.1
myproject1: in his venv i have in my req.txt

numpy==3.0
my_package1
my_package2

how to avoid dependence conflicts  when i do a pip install req.txt without change manually change version of dependances one by one

If my_package1: use numpy==1.8 and my_packge2: use numpy==2.1 and your project uses both of those then it's impossible to work - they both specify an exact version and the versions are different. If you just care to have any numpy installed then you could remove all the version specifiers like ==1.8 etc and let the package manager find a version that is compatible with all dependencies. Usually libraries won't put an exact version constraint so it's usually possible.

While I can relate to your problem, asking for software/tutorial recommendations seems to be off-topic on SO. There's a bunch of Python dependency management tools (like Poetry, PDM, Pipenv, etc.) that are designed to solve the problem you've described and resolve dependency versions automatically, but choosing one is opinion-based.

You're probably looking for virtual environments - this will wrap pip and install packages to a specific location
python3 -m venv path1      # once to create each venv
source path1/bin/activate  # per-session

If you have packages that need to be installed to a system, you may consider Docker or another container system

Virtual environments won't solve the issue if the question is about getting one non-conflicting numpy version in the same Python environment (of myproject1).

certainly, though it feels like 2+ envs & REST here .. really the Question is too broad and the Asker should probably do more work to first minimize and closely target a short range of version(s) supported by those dependencies .. and if they really have discrete parts which need to communicate but require different numpy versions, consider whether they need or want to support some interchange format(s), cost of copying data vs zerocopy/shared memory, what level the API should occur at, if they can rewrite their application such that numeric processing is contained in one part of it, etc.
